# Zend Framework Dependency Injection vs Symfony2 Dependency Injection

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, symfony

I've been using Symfony2 DI a lot for some of my projects recently, and just started trying Zend DI. What I can see is SYmfony2 DI is a lot better than Zend DI as it also provides the following features which don't exist in Zend DI:

- Configure the services using XML, YML, PHP,...
- Tag feature
- Event/Dispatcher

Please correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Give ZF2 a chance, they are still in beta. Some if not all of these features will likely be implemented at some point.

Answer (score 1):

- AFAIK zend DI can be fileld from any format that can return an array (XML, INI, YMP, PHP, NEON, even CSV maybe :D)
- what does that do?
- ZF2 has a powerful EventManager and Dispatching is also set up in the DI config - anything implementing Dispatchable interface can be dispatched - but I can't see how Events and Dispatching relates to DI implementation.